# Do I make a EFRepository for each API Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

still pretty new to ASP.NET.  I have two models, and two API controllers.  I was hoping I could create all the methods for both controllers in my EFRepository, but it seems to only let me use objects from the first model I built.  My question is, do I just create another repository for the second model/API?  Or is it best practice to create a generic and use server-side services for my methods?  Or is there something else I am missing in my thought process? Thanks!

Record Model

```
namespace Train.Models {
    public class Record {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Cars Model

```
namespace Train.Models {
    public class Cars {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string EmptyOrLoaded { get; set; }
        public string CarType { get; set; }
        //Hopper, flatbed, tank, gondola, etc.
        public string ShippedBy { get; set; }
        //UP(Union Pacific) or BNSF
        public string RailcarNumber { get; set; }
        //public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string RecordId { get; set; }
        public virtual Record Record { get; set; }

    }
}
```

API CarsController Method

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Cars car) {
        car.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }
        _repo.SaveCar(car);
        return Created("", car);
    }
```

API Recordcontroler Method

```
  public IHttpActionResult PostRecord(Record record) {
        var UserId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }
        _repo.SaveRecord(record);
        return Created("", record);
    }
```

Save Car Method in EFRepository

```
   public void SaveCar(Cars carToSave) {
        if (carToSave.Id == 0) {
            _db.Cars.Add(carToSave);
            _db.SaveChanges();

        } else {
            var original = this.Find(carToSave.Id);
            original.EmptyOrLoaded = carToSave.EmptyOrLoaded;
            original.CarType = carToSave.CarType;
            original.ShippedBy = carToSave.ShippedBy;
            original.RailcarNumber = carToSave.RailcarNumber;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I hope you mean a new instance of the repository, not a whole new repository. Can you supply some of the basic code from your controllers to demonstrate?

Comment: added code.  When I go into my EFRepository and try to make a SaveRecord method, it is still trying to use the properties belonging to the Cars class.